# Entity - Model (EAV) system with delta updates

Tags: sql

I am trying to create my first eav system that can handle updates as well.

The user can create models with list and objects inside and with references other models. the user can then create instances of the model ModelDataFields.

First we have the ModelParameteres. that will store all the models and their parameters and the fields and their parameters.

A parameter is like 'name'or 'islist' or 'order' or whatever. We have a enum for that.
UpdateType is 'created' or 'updated' or 'deleted'.
updatedby is UserId.
Updated is datetime stamp and delta for what is updated.
Model is ModelId
Value is some user data for the parameter like the name value when parameter is 'name'.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ModelParameters]
                 (
                    [UpdateType]    [TINYINT]           NOT NULL,
                    [UpdatedBy]     [uniqueidentifier]  NOT NULL,
                    [Updated]       [datetime2](0)      NOT NULL,
                    [Model]         [uniqueidentifier]  NOT NULL,
                    [Field]         [uniqueidentifier]  NULL,
                    [Parameter]     [smallint]          NOT NULL,
                    [Value]         [nvarchar](MAX)    NULL
                 );

 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ModelParameters]
                    ON [dbo].[ModelParameters]([Updated] DESC, [Model], [Field]);
```

Then we have the ModelDataFields that holds data records for each of the fields in a model. the ModelData is the id of each instance of the model.
the index is when we have a user list of some field soo we know what data belongs together in a dynamic list.

UpdateType is 'created' or 'updated' or 'deleted'.
updatedby is UserId.
Updated is datetime stamp and delta for what is updated.

Value is the current value for the modeldata => field => index?.
LastValue is for undo and restoring in case of deleting.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ModelDataFields] (
                [UpdateType]     [TINYINT]           NOT NULL,
                [UpdatedBy]      [uniqueidentifier]  NOT NULL,
                [Updated]        [datetime2](0)      NOT NULL,
                [ModelData]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL,
                [ModelField]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL,
                [Index]          INT                 NULL,
                [Value]          NVARCHAR (MAX)      NULL,
                [LastValue]      NVARCHAR (MAX)      NULL,
            );



CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ModelDataFields]
                ON [dbo].[ModelDataFields]([Updated] DESC, [ModelData], [ModelField]);
```

Do i need multi tables for the ModeldataFields like for each model or is this fine? do you see something else wrong, We are gonna go with EAV so it not a question about EAV vs setting up tables.